# Wrapping output of an array to CSV conversion in quotations in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing

What I'm wanting to find out is how to have every entry passed from the array to the CSV at the end of the program be wrapped by " "'s to allow Excel to read it correctly. I know this needs to be done before or during the "push" at line 34, but doing "streets.push('"'+street_name+'"')" results in every entry being surrounded by THREE quotation marks, which doesn't make much sense to me.

```
#!ruby.exe
require 'csv'

puts "Please enter a file name:" #user input file name (must be in same 
folder as this file)
file = gets.chomp

begin
  File.open(file, 'r')
rescue
  print "Failed to open #{file}\n"
  exit
end #makes sure that the file exists, if it does not it posts an error

data_file = File.new(file)
data = [] #initializes array for addresses from .csv
counter=0 #set counter up to allow for different sized files to be used 
without issue

CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true) do |row|
  data << row.to_hash
  counter+=1
end #goes through .csv one line ar a time

data.reject(&:empty?)

puts "Which column do you want to parse?"
column = gets.chomp

i=0

streets = []

while (i<counter)
  address = data[i][column]
  street_name = address.gsub(/^((\d[a-zA-Z])|[^a-zA-Z])*/, '')
  streets.push(street_name)
  i+=1
end

streets.reject(&:empty?)

puts "What do you want the output to be called?"
new_file = gets.chomp

CSV.open(new_file, "w", :write_headers=> true, :headers => [column]) do |hdr|
  hdr << streets
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `:force_quotes` option to the CSV library to have it quote everything in the csv for you:

```
base_options = {headers: ['first,col', 'second column'], write_headers: true}
options = [{}, {force_quotes: true}]

data = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['c', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f']
]

options.each do |option|
  result = CSV.generate(base_options.merge(option)) do |csv|
    data.each do |datum|
      csv << datum
    end
  end

  puts "#{option}:\n#{result}"
end
```

For instance, in this small script, by default, the only thing that gets quoted is the first column header because it contains a comma. By passing in `force_quotes: true`, in the second pass though, everything gets quoted.

**Output:**

```
{}:
"first,col",second column
a,b
c,d
e,f
{:force_quotes=>true}:
"first,col","second column"
"a","b"
"c","d"
"e","f"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map to process the array before putting it in csv.

```
   streets.map!{|s| '"'+s+'"'}
```